# SEO-friendly static snapshots of single-page web apps without using a dynamic server

Tags: ajax, seo, github-pages

### Scenario:

I'm hosting a single-page application on GitHub Pages. When accessed via browser, JavaScript processes `#!` URLs and updates the UI.

I also want my app's content to appear in search results. Since I'm using GulpJS already, I want to add a task to create and save pre-rendered HTML snapshots of my page to accommodate web crawlers.

### Problem:

My content is served by GitHub Pages, so I don't have any way to handle the `_escaped_fragment_` parameter that web crawlers send. Every tutorial I've found on AJAX SEO assumes you are hosting your content on e.g. a NodeJS or Apache server and have a way to process such URL parameters.

### Question:

Can a single-page web app be SEO-friendly when hosted on a static file server (e.g. GitHub Pages)? Is there a special directory I can use? Some special Sitemap or robots.txt configuration? Something else?

### What I've found already:

- [Frequently Asked Questions (via Google Webmasters)](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/faq)
- [How do I create an HTML snapshot? (via Google Webmasters)](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/html-snapshot)
- [AngularJS and SEO (via Yearofmoo)](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2012/11/angularjs-and-seo.html)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: @JohnConde It is about SEO, but it deals specifically with AJAX development on static file servers. This, in my opinion, falls under ["practical, answerable problems that are unique to software development"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: You may find some helpful resources here: http://www.staticapps.org/

Comment: @JoelGlovier Thanks for the link! I don't see a solution for my specific problem yet, but the site looks promising